# getting the actual number that is stored

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal, ieee-754

I have a project to create a scientific calculator using taylor series. Moreover I am analysing a number to the ieee 754 standard floating point system.

In my calculator the user chooses if they want single or double precision: I use float and double variables, 
 and then I analyze the number following the ieee 754 spec.

If the user wants double precision the analysis goes like this:

```
double analyze=3.45
BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal(analyze)
```

which gives me

```
3.45000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

1. Is this number is the actual number  which is stored in binary format in the pc memory?
2. If it isn't is any way I can have the real value of the number that is stored?
3. Also why does this happen?

   `double analyze=0.5`
   `BigDecimal db=new BigBecimal(analyze)`

It prints only `0.5` - why do I lose significant digits?

can someone tell me why does this happens

```
        BigDecimal one=new BigDecimal(0.1);
        BigDecimal five=one.multiply(new BigDecimal(5)) ;
        System.out.println("5 times 0.1 is "+" "+ five);

        System.out.println("But the 0.5 in BigDecimal is " + " "+ new BigDecimal(0.5));
```

by running this you get
               5 times 0.1 is  0.5000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125
                But the 0.5 in BigDecimal is  0.5

Comment: No, that's not the stored number.  The stored number is *binary*.  You can access it with `Double.doubleToRawLongBits`.

Comment: i have to make also an other question whick makes me confussed if i convert a float e.g 0.5 to bigdecimal it gives me an other result than converting 0.1 to bigdecimal and adding it 5 times  !!!

Comment: The two values should be very similar, but, due to rounding errors, you may see some difference is the least significant one or two digits.

Comment: @HotLicks: That is the stored number. doubleToRawLongBits will produce the encoding, which is not the stored number, just the means by which it is represented. E.g., for integers, when the **number** stored is eleven, the **encoding** is off, off, off,… on, off, on, on. For the purposes in this question, I think user1911078 does not care about the encoding, just the value represented.

Comment: you are right Hotlicks !!! i have a form like every scientific calculator the user makes any action and has the capapility of opening a second form which there a make the ieee 754 analyze . e.g if the user press 3.456 and has selected sigle precision i want to saw him the real value of the number with 32 bit precision that is stored no the binary value

Answer (score 3):

> 1.i want to ask you is this number is the actual number which is stored in binary format in the pc memory ??

Yes.

> 2.if it isn't is any way i can have the real value of the number that is stored

Well, it is, so no problem.

> 1. it prints me only -->0.5 why do i loose signifigant digits?

You don't; `0.5` is the exact number being stored in binary format.

Comment: The "real" value of the number is the binary representation accessed with doubleToRawLongBits.

Comment: It's not clear to me that that's the "real" value the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, 3.45000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125 is the actual value stored in a double when you convert the numeral “3.45” to the common double format.
2. That is the real value.
3. You did not show the method by which you printed 0.5. As I recall, one of the common display mechanisms in Java just prints as many digits as needed to exactly represent the value, when that is possible. It does not print trailing zeroes because they are redundant.

You might wonder “Well, if only .5 is printed, how do I know the number is .5000000000 and not .5000000001 or something like that?” The answer is that, if the number were different from .5, more digits would be printed, because the display mechanism is defined to do that. So you can rely in the fact that “.5” means .5, nothing more, nothing less.

If this is a school project, then you probably do not need to worry about 3.45 being represented with a slightly different value. Just go ahead and compute using the value that is in the double.

Also, Taylor series are a poor choice for real calculators, because they are designed to be accurate near a point, but you would want a series that is accurate over an interval. There are other series that spread their errors out better, so that they need many fewer terms to get an accurate result. I would only use a Taylor series if it was suggested as part of the school project.

Comment: thanks a lot first of all!! no it a Graduate project !! so you mean that if you type 0.5 it will store the 0.5 excacly are you sure cause my proffesor said me that if you type e.g 0.5 its stores a number with more precision !!!

Comment: I mean, yes, it stores more digits than just `0.5` alone, but the extra digits are all zeroes.  It stores the exact value `0.5`.  (There would be no reason to print `0.50000` or however many zeroes, because you can't translate precision in binary to precision in decimal.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The [BigDecimal(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) constructor "Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value." The BigDecimal [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29) method displays the exact value.
2. N/A
3. 0.5 is exactly representable as a double. The BigDecimal(0.5) result has unscaled value 5 and scale 1. It meets the BigDecimal [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29) conditions for display without an exponent. The number of digits after the decimal point is equal to the scale, 1.

Your example code:

```
    BigDecimal one=new BigDecimal(0.1);
    BigDecimal five=one.multiply(new BigDecimal(5)) ;
```

brings out a problem with using the BigDecimal double constructor unless you are probing double representation. 0.1 is not exactly representable as a double, so your "one" is not exactly 0.1, even though `BigDecimal("0.1")` would be exact.

More generally, the exact value of a double always has the form `a/(2**b)` where `a` and `b` are integers and `"**"` represents exponentiation. `(a * 5**b)/(10**b)` has the same value, and is exactly representable as a BigDecimal with scale b.

Answer (score -2):

In general, float and double will **not** exactly represent a decimal number (except for powers of two and a few other "sweet spots").  The number is stored internally in binary.  You can access the internal representation with `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` or `Float.floatToRawIntBits`.

Comment: Every float and double exactly represent some decimal number.

Comment: @StephenCanon -- Not every decimal number has a float/double representation.  (See, eg, 3.45 above.)

Comment: that's the converse of what I said.

Comment: But exactly what I said, and because something is true does not mean its converse is true.